# Error while reading ms-excel file in coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion-8

I am executing SQL to read data from MS-Excel in **ColdFusion**. My SQL is:

```
SELECT *  FROM "Excel 8.0; DATABASE=C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\MyFiles\SaleTemplate.xls; HDR=YES".[Template$] WHERE Title is not null and Title<>''
```

But I am getting this error:

> "Excel 8.0; DATABASE=C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\MyFiles\SaleTemplate.xls; HDR=YES"' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The query I use for Excel data through an Access datasource is formatted like this:

```
select *
from [Template$]
in 'C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\MyFiles\SaleTemplate.xls' 'Excel 8.0;'
```